# Sum of series using integration

Tags: calculus, summation

In certain special series, we can use the sigma notation to obtain the sum of $n$ terms. For example;

$$1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3 +\cdots+ n^3 = \frac {n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$$

The sum can also be written as

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^3$$

Why can we not simply integrate the function $n^3$? Using the aforementioned formula gives the correct answer. whereas integrating the function doesn't. Why is there a disparity between the two?

Comment: The integral of $x^3$ from say $0$ to $n$ is the area under the smooth curve $y=x^3$. The sum can be thought of as a sum of areas of rectangles that approximate the area under the smooth curve. No reason that they should be the same. But one is often a reasonably good *approximation* of the other.

Comment: See also: the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

Comment: Or [this note on Discrete Calculus](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/DCalc.pdf) by Brian Hamrick

Comment: Integral is for check some qualities like convergence. But sum is to get the exact answer.

Comment: The Riemann–Stieltjes integral can be used to handle integration with respect to a discrete distribution (which can be made equivalent to a sum) or a mixed distribution. This link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann–Stieltjes_integral is not wonderful, but gives some references.

Comment: "Why is there a disparity?" is the wrong question. Why would you expect equality? Why are you surprised that doing two different things leads to two different answers?

Comment: Gerry, thing is, I'm not entirely familiar with calculus yet. I was told that integration and summation are pretty much the same thing. I understand, though, that integration removes the constrictions of simple summation. But until now, I thought that the sigma itself could be substituted by the integral. Now i understand that the sigma allows us to sum discrete series, whereas the integral includes everything in between.

Comment: @Henry Thank you so much for that link. You don't know how long I've wanted that. Having just spent a happy hour working out how I can do some sort of discrete integration and getting answers but clunkily, that is utterly beautiful. Thank you thank you thank you.

Answer (score 1):

let's consider $1^3+2^3$ for now

when i use integration, i mean $1^3 + (1+dx)^3 + (1+2dx)^3 + ... + (2-dx)^3 + 2^3$, where $dx$ is a very small number

while the sigma notation means sum of 2 numbers only in this case, $1^3 + 2^3$.

Comment: So basically, the integral is the infinite summation of the cubes of all the real numbers lying between the said limits, whereas the sigma only adds the cubes of the two limits, right?
If the above understanding is correct, then I have one more question. Isn't an infinite summation possible only for numbers lesser than 1? If so, can we add the cubes of all real numbers lying between, say 1 and 2?